# Some questions about titlepage and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

I would like to create a title with `titlepage` and `tikz`. However, I don't know very well these both tools and I need your help.

Here is what I've got now and, then, I have three questions:

[image]

### 1. How can I move a little bit up the black headband?

I would like to reduce the spacing between the black headband and the top. Like I use `titlepage` code from another person, I don't know how to do this.

### 2. How to add another headband with a different color?

I would like to add another headband with a different color above the black one. The color would be `\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{0,11,23,24}`. Here is the result I would like to obtain:

[image]

### 3. How to add a vertical banner on the right?

Here is what I understand by "vertical banner". This banner will contain a logo and some text below the logo. You can notice the effect at the bottom of the banner ; it would be very nice if something similar is doable with tikz.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[some]{background}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{0,0,0,80}
\DeclareFixedFont{\bigsf}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{1cm}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \path [fill=titlepagecolor] (-0.5\paperwidth,5) rectangle (0.5\paperwidth,10);  
\end{tikzpicture}}
}
\makeatletter                       
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {\large \@author}}              
\makeatother


\author{Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\BgThispage
\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=4cm}
\vspace*{2cm}
\noindent
\textcolor{white}{\bigsf My title\\ in two lines}
\vspace*{2.5cm}\par
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \printauthor
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage} \hspace{15pt}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
    \rule{1pt}{175pt}
\end{minipage} \hspace{-10pt}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
\vspace{5pt}
\newenvironment{test}{\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
    \begin{abstract} 
An abstract is a brief summary of a research article, thesis, review, conference proceeding or any in-depth analysis of a particular subject or discipline, and is often used to help the reader quickly ascertain the paper's purpose. When used, an abstract always appears at the beginning of a manuscript, acting as the point-of-entry for any given scientific paper or patent application. Abstracting and indexing services for various academic disciplines are aimed at compiling a body of literature for that particular subject.
    \end{abstract}

\end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't really need the `background` package here; it's enough to have a `tikzpicture` with the `remember picture, overlay` options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,shadows}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{0,0,0,80}
\definecolor{titlepagecolor2}{RGB}{196,175,153}

\DeclareFixedFont{\bigsf}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{1cm}

\makeatletter                       
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {{\large \@author}}}              
\makeatother

\author{Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author \\Author}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}


\newgeometry{left=1cm,right=4cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
% the black stripe with the title
\node[
  fill=titlepagecolor,
  anchor=north west,
  text width=\paperwidth,
  text height=2cm,
  text depth=2cm,
  inner xsep=1cm,
  font=\color{white}\bigsf 
  ] 
 at ([yshift=-2.5cm]current page.north west) (blackrect) {My title \\ in two lines};
% the khaki stripe
\path[fill=titlepagecolor2] 
  (blackrect.north west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,2cm);
% the banner
\node[
  signal,
  signal from=north,
  signal pointer angle=150,
  fill=white,
  drop shadow={shadow xshift=0pt},
  rotate=-90,
  text width=6cm,
  text height=5cm,
  anchor=north west
  ] (banner) at ([xshift=-3cm,yshift=1cm]blackrect.north east) {};
% the image in the banner
\node[anchor=north] at ([yshift=-1cm]banner.west)
  {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}};
% the text in the banner
\node[
  anchor=south,
  text width=3cm,
  align=center,
  font=\itshape] 
  at ([yshift=2cm]banner.east) {Some text that goes in the banner};
% images on footer
\node[anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt]
  at ([yshift=3cm,xshift=-1cm]current page.south) 
  {\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=1cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt]
  at ([yshift=3cm,xshift=1cm]current page.south) 
  {\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=1cm]{example-image-c}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{4.5cm}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \printauthor
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage} \hspace{15pt}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
    \rule{1pt}{175pt}
\end{minipage} \hspace{-10pt}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
\vspace{5pt}
\newenvironment{test}{\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
    \begin{abstract} 
An abstract is a brief summary of a research article, thesis, review, conference proceeding or any in-depth analysis of a particular subject or discipline, and is often used to help the reader quickly ascertain the paper's purpose. When used, an abstract always appears at the beginning of a manuscript, acting as the point-of-entry for any given scientific paper or patent application. Abstracting and indexing services for various academic disciplines are aimed at compiling a body of literature for that particular subject.
 \end{abstract}
\end{minipage}

\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

[image]

To answer your questions:

1. I used `\node`s; in this way, you can easily place some elements using the node anchors. Controlling the value used for `yshift` in the `blackrect` node, you can vertically shift the elements at will.
2. The black horizontal stripe is simply a rectangular node filled with some color; to add the other stripe, use another node and place it at the desired position with the help of the `blackrect` anchors.
3. The banner is simply a `signal` shape (from the `shapes.symbols` library) with a drop shadow.
4. The images at the bottom can also be included inside `\node`s.

Comment: @ppr You're welcome! Glad I could help!

Comment: Sorry to bother you but perhaps you have the solution to another problem : I would like to include a centered picture on the footer of the titlepage. If I use `\vfill\centering\includepicture...` the picture is not centered and not in the footer of the page.

Comment: @ppr Please see my updated answer; you can use another `\node` to place this new element at the desired position.

Comment: Wonderful! In fact I have two pictures (logos). I want them side by side. I tried to add two `\node` but they overlaps...

Comment: @ppr where should they go? Both in the footer, side by side?

Comment: Absolutely. The tricky point is how to centering them...

Comment: @ppr Please see my updated answer; the trick is to set the proper anchors, and then control the separation between them with an appropriate `xshift` value (I used `-1cm` and `1cm`, so they will be `2cm` away, but choose the values you need.).

Comment: Nice, `tikz` is really a powerful tool ; I think I will use it more often (and try to handle it). Thanks again.

Comment: @ppr You are welcome! Yes. TikZ is really powerful.